# resolving a differential equation within setting of Newtonian mechanics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have just started studying differential equations, and by chance need to resolve the following equation within an exercise about Newtonian mechanics in another course:
$v(t)'+\frac{γ}{m}v(t)=g$

I know the correct answer is $v(t)=c_1e^\frac{-γt}{m}+\frac{gm}{γ}$, but I would like to understand the procedures that get me there, so that I can learn from it for my O.D.E. course.

I have learnt how to resolve simple homogeneous equations of the type $v(t)'+\frac{γ}{m}v(t)=0$, as well as non-homogeneous equations. But as 'g' is not a variable (at least not in this setting), it leaves with a new type of equation that I do not know how to resolve.

Any insights would be very much appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equation

$$\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{γ}{m}v(t)=g$$

and there are several ways  you can solve it with

In this case you can split the equation into two equations, by taking on board that the function $v(t)$ can be in one case constant (null derivative) and then solve the homogeneous RELATED equation (RHS null), and finally sum the solutions of the two sub-equations

For istance in the case $\frac{γ}{m}v(t)=g$ you get

$$v_{1}(t)=\frac{m}{γ}g$$

and in the other one
$$\frac{dv}{dt}+\frac{γ}{m}v(t)=0$$

leading into $v_{2}(t)=ce^{-\frac{γ}{m}}t$

and finally you have to sum the two

EDIT, you can also transform the LHS as a derivative of a product by simply multiplying by $e^{\frac{γ}{m}}t$ and obtain

$$\frac{dv}{dt}e^{\frac{γ}{m}}t+\frac{γ}{m}v(t)e^{\frac{γ}{m}}t=ge^{\frac{γ}{m}}t$$

and you could proceed onwards.